# Unable to write apache2 config for sub path of my domain

Tags: apache2, conf

My app root:
    /public/index.php
    /public/front/index.html

I want to ***mydomain.com/api*** to serve from ***/public/index.php***, and
my frontend i.e the static site ***mydomain.com/*** from ***/public/front/index.html***.

I have tried using **proxy** and **location** with document root as  **/public/** but failed to deliver the results in Apache2.

Need a correct way around. (Already using a simple conf for nginx to do the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) directive to map specific URL paths to locations on your file system, regardless of their locations relative to the designated DocumentRoot.

```
DocumentRoot /public/front
Alias /api/   /public/
```

Please note that doing the above will also expose your front end on `http://example.com/api/front/` but such is the unfortunate result  of the odd directory layout that you have chosen...